# R ggplot with two series: points and errorbars with legends

Tags: r, ggplot2

If I have a dataframe like this:

```
obs<-rnorm(20)
d<-data.frame(year=2000:2019,obs=obs,pred=obs+rnorm(20,.1))
d$pup<-d$pred+.5
d$plow<-d$pred-.5
d$obs[20]<-NA
d
```

And I want the observation and model prediction error bars to look something like:

```
(p1<-ggplot(data=d)+aes(x=year)
 +geom_point(aes(y=obs),color='red',shape=19)
 +geom_point(aes(y=pred),color='blue',shape=3)
 +geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=plow,ymax=pup))
 )
```

[image: observations and predictive model error bars]

How do I add a legend/scale/key identifying the red points as observations and the blue plusses with error bars as point predictions with ranges?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787578/problem-with-legend-while-plotting-data-from-two-data-frame?rq=1 looks helpful.

Comment: No, you're better off melting your data frame first, so that you have a single column with values `obs` and `pred` to map to `color` and `shape`.

Comment: @Joran: The observations come from one datasource, and the model predictions and the error bars come from another.  I suppose that with complex data, this is advising that a simpler plotting data frame should be produced for each graphic.

Comment: Where they come from doesn't matter. You asked how to create the legend, and the best way to do that in ggplot is to map variables to aesthetics and _avoid_ multiple lines with the same geom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `ggplot` solution that does not require melting and grouping.

```
set.seed(1)      # for reproducible example
obs <- rnorm(20)
d   <- data.frame(year=2000:2019,obs,pred=obs+rnorm(20,.1))
d$obs[20]<-NA
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d,aes(x=year))+
  geom_point(aes(y=obs,color="obs",shape="obs"))+
  geom_point(aes(y=pred,color="pred",shape="pred"))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=pred-0.5,ymax=pred+0.5))+
  scale_color_manual("Legend",values=c(obs="red",pred="blue"))+
  scale_shape_manual("Legend",values=c(obs=19,pred=3))
```

[image]

This creates a color and shape scale wiith two components each ("obs" and "pred"). Then uses `scale_*_manual(...)` to set the values for those scales ("red","blue") for color, and (19,3) for scale.

Generally, if you have only two categories, like "obs" and "pred", then this is a reasonable way to go use `ggplot`, and avoids merging everything into one data frame. If you have more than two categories, or if they are integral to the dataset (e.g., actual categorical variables), then you are much better off doing this as in the other answer.

Note that your example left out the column `year` so your code does not run.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one solution melting pred/obs into one column. Can't post image due to rep.

```
library(ggplot2)
obs <- rnorm(20)
d <- data.frame(dat=c(obs,obs+rnorm(20,.1)))
d$pup <- d$dat+.5
d$plow <- d$dat-.5
d$year <- rep(2000:2019,2)
d$lab <- c(rep("Obs", 20), rep("Pred", 20))

p1<-ggplot(data=d, aes(x=year)) +
geom_point(aes(y = dat, colour = factor(lab), shape = factor(lab))) +
geom_errorbar(data = d[21:40,], aes(ymin=plow,ymax=pup), colour = "blue") +
scale_shape_manual(name = "Legend Title", values=c(6,1)) +
scale_colour_manual(name = "Legend Title", values=c("red", "blue"))
p1
```

[image]

edit: Thanks for the rep. Image added