# Creating legend in geom_histogram for elements created from geom_vline

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, histogram, legend

Here is an example data set:

```
structure(list(Age = c(6L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L,6L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L,6L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L), Year = c(2011, 
2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011,     2011, 2011 )), .Names = c("Age", "Year"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to create a legend that will show the three components that I list in my geom_vline command below. I've read several examples on s.overflow but nothing seems to be working..

This is what I have so far:

```
# to create standard errors and mean lines to plot on histogram
se <- function(x) sqrt(var(x)/length(x))
se_11 <- se(Age_2011$Age)
mean_11 <- mean(Age_2011$Age)
se_11_plus <- mean_11 + se_11
se_11_minus <- mean_11 - se_11

#plot
p11_age <- ggplot(Age_2011, aes(x=Age))+ 
geom_histogram(aes(y=(..count..)/sum(..count..)), binwidth=1, origin=-.5, fill="white",    color="black", show_guide=TRUE)+             
scale_y_continuous(labels=percent_format(), name="Frequency (%)")+  ## plotting in     percent frequency
xlab("Age (years)")+
scale_x_continuous(limits=c(1,45), breaks=seq(1,45,1))+
scale_colour_discrete(name="Units", guide="legend")+ #attempting to create legend

# vertical lines for mean and standard errors
geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(Age_2011$Age), na.rm=T), color="red", linetype="dashed",     size=1, show_guide=TRUE)+
geom_vline(aes(xintercept=se_11_plus), color ="blue", show_guide=TRUE)+
geom_vline(aes(xintercept=se_11_minus), color="blue", show_guide=TRUE)+

# creating custom legends using guides
scale_linetype_manual(name="test", labels =c("median", "test", "test2"), values =     c("median"=1, "test"=2, "test3"=3))+
theme(legend.key=element_rect(fill="white", color ="white"))+
theme(legend.background=element_blank())+
guides(colour=guide_legend(override.aes=list(linetype=0)),   fill=guide_legend(override.aes=list(linetype=0)), 
    shape=guide_legend(override.aes=list(linetype=0)),
    linetype=guide_legend())+

#title and background
ggtitle("Age Frequency Histogram of 2011 Catch")+
theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),     panel.background=element_rect(colour="black", fill="white"))
```

All of the geom_vlines show however I can't figure out how to get a legend when there is really only one histogram "series" and all I want in the legend are the vertical lines.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You seem to want linetypes for `median`, `test` and `test2` but I see no other references to these. Also, there are only 2 colors: red for the mean and blue for the sem. It's not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish>>

Comment: @jlhoward, the median, test and test2 were supposed to be filler names for the 3 vertical lines I would like displayed in a legend. Simply, I want one legend with three lines titled median, test and test2. What you see above is my attempt to do that however, it is obviously not working out. Does that clarify?

Comment: See jlhoward's solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24148423/r-ggplot-with-two-series-points-and-errorbars-with-legends/24149621#24149621

Comment: @Elizabeth - Not really. So you want lines labeled "median", "test", and "test2". But your actual lines correspond to mean, mean-se, and mean+se. And there are only 2 colors: blue for mean +/- se, and red for mean.

Comment: @jlhoward, yes I did have lines labeled mean, mean-se and mean+se however for the moment I chose to label them median, test and test2 in the legend.. Yes, there are only 2 colors. The code above was my attempt to create a legend but obviously I was having problems creating code that was effective. My misunderstanding. Just looking for clarity on this matter.  It seems that someone above pointed me to one of your previous solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this more or less what you're asking for?

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
p11_age <- ggplot(Age_2011, aes(x=Age))+ 
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..count../sum(..count..)), binwidth=1, origin=-0.5, fill=NA, color="black")+             
  scale_y_continuous(name="Frequency (%)", labels=percent_format())+
  scale_x_continuous(name="Age (years)",limits=c(1,45), breaks=seq(1,45,1))+  
  # vertical lines for mean and standard errors
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean_11, color="Mean", linetype="Mean"), size=1, show_guide=TRUE)+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=se_11_plus, color="Std.Err", linetype="Std.Err"), show_guide=TRUE)+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=se_11_minus, color="Std.Err", linetype="Std.Err"), show_guide=TRUE)+
  scale_colour_manual(name="Units", values=c(Std.Err="blue",Mean="red"))+
  scale_linetype_manual(name="Units", values=c(Mean="dashed",Std.Err="solid"), guide=FALSE)+
  ggtitle("Age Frequency Histogram of 2011 Catch")+
  theme(legend.background=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor=element_blank(), 
        panel.background=element_rect(colour="black", fill="white"))
p11_age
```

So here we add the 3 `geom_vline` layers, using color and linetype aesthetics *inside the call to `aes(...)`*. Then we map the "Mean" and "Std.Err" colors to "red" and "blue" using `scale_color_manual(...)`, and we map the "Mean" and "Std.Err" linetypes to "dashed" and "solid" in the call to `scale_linetype_manual(...)`. Note the use of named vectors in the `values=...` argument. We also turn off display of the linetype guide by using `guide=FALSE` in the call to `scale_linetype_manual(...)`. The reason for this is that otherwise the lines in the legend would be solid and dashed (I think this is what you were trying to do with `override_aes`).

Comment: Thanks! I had looked at some other examples last night and none seemed to help. Appreciate your time and patience.